# Relational Query - 2 degrees away

Tags: google-app-maker

I have three models:

1. Timesheets
2. Employee
3. Manager

I am looking for all timesheets that need to be approved by a manager (many timesheets per employee, one manager per employee).

I have tried creating datasources and prefetching both Employee and Employee.Manager, but I so far no success as of yet.

Is there a trick to this? Do I need to load the query and then do another load? Or create an intermediary datasource that holds both the Timesheet and Employee data or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by applying a query filter to the datasource onDataLoad event or another event. For example, you could bind the value of a dropdown with Managers to:
@datasource.query.filters.Employee.Manager._equals 
- assuming that the datasource of the widget is set to Timesheets.

If you are linking to the page from another page, you could also call a script instead of using a preset action. On the link click, invoke the script below, passing it the desired manager object from the linking page.

```js
function loadPageTimesheets(manager){
  app.showPage(app.pages.Timesheets);
  app.pages.Timesheets.datasource.query.filters.Employee.Manager._equals = manager;
  app.pages.Timesheets.datasource.load();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to redesign your app a little bit to use full power of App Maker. You can go with [Directory Model](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/directory) (Manager -> Employees) plus one table with data (Timesheets). In this case your timesheets query can look similar to this:

```js
// Server side script
function getTimesheets(query) {
  var managerEmail = query.parameters.ManagerEmail;
  var dirQuery = app.models.Directory.newQuery();

  dirQuery.filters.PrimaryEmail._equals = managerEmail;
  dirQuery.prefetch.DirectReports._add();

  var people = dirQuery.run();

  if (people.length === 0) {
   return [];
  }

  var manager = people[0];

  // Subordinates lookup can look fancier if you need recursively
  // include everybody down the hierarchy chart. In this case
  // it also will make sense to update prefetch above to include
  // reports of reports of reports...
  var subortinatesEmails = manager.DirectReports.map(function(employee) {
    return employee.PrimaryEmail;
  });

  var tsQuery = app.models.Timesheet.newQuery();
  tsQuery.filters.EmployeeEmail._in = subortinatesEmails;

  return tsQuery.run();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, we don't want every directory user to be in the app though. We do use the Directory to make filling the Employee table easier.